# How to access ADL2 with Service Principal in Synapse?

Tags: azure-synapse

In my Synapse workspace I added a linked service to ADL2 as shown in the screenshot.

Using "Test Connection" I can successfully connect to the container and path provided. Connection to the linked service fails and is expected as the principal only has access at folder level.

[image]

With the linked service added, I can see it show up in my workspace. However, it has a red "X" as the icon and I cannot browse its content:

[image]

When I'm trying to query the content, I get an error saying `"Content of directory on path https://adl2abc.dfs.core.windows.net/container/some/path/** cannot be listed"`

Although this is the exact path I used when testing the connection. The query I'm using:

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://adl2abc.dfs.core.windows.net/container/some/path/**',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
```

What is the point of defining an authentication method in the linked service if the workspace is then apparently not using it? How can I configure it to use that principal?

Answer (score 0):

I am having ADLS gen2 storage account I want to query the data of it through Synapse by creating linked service authentication with service principal authentication for that I added that service principal as `storage blob data contributor role` by following below procedure:

Go to IAM of ADLS Gen 2 click on `ADD` option and select `Add role assignment` option

[image]

Select the `user or group` option and click on `select memeber` Option and selected the SPN and click on `Review +Assign` Option

[image]

It assigned successfully. I created a linked service of ADLS Gen2 in Synapse workspace by filling `TenantId`, `ClientId`,`Secret`  values and `To linked service` as  `Test connection` option . It tested successfully.

[image]

I created a database and query the data of storage Gen 2 by using below code:

```
SELECT
TOP  100 *
FROM
OPENROWSET(
   BULK  'https://synpool.dfs.core.windows.net/synfiles/input/*',
   FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
) AS [result]
```

I got below error:

[image]

But I was able to query by using below procedure:

[image]

I run above provided query, it executed successfully without any issue.

[image]